# Timed background image change with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to make a function for changing the background image of a div every 6s with jQuery.

Here is what I have, but it doesn't work, doesn't even load first image.

Anyone could help me fix this please?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var body = $(‘#main’);
  var backgrounds = new Array(
    ‘url(../style/background.jpg)’,
    ‘url(../style/background2.jpg)’,
    ‘url(../style/background3.jpg)’
  );
  var current = 0;

  function nextBackground() {
    body.css(
      ‘background’,
      backgrounds[current = ++current % backgrounds.length]
    );
    setTimeout(nextBackground, 6000);
  }

  setTimeout(nextBackground, 6000);
  body.css(‘background’, backgrounds[0]);
});
```

Comment: Put all your code inside the `$(document).ready` function, and try again. Also, make sure your links to images resolve correctly.

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console?  Do the URLs match the relative path of the rendered url/page?

Comment: @NickSalloum I have all the code inside the `$(document).ready`

Comment: Check the console for errors.

Answer (score 0):

Ahh.. the typical case of deceitful character.

On your second line, near `$('#main');` you have used two different single inverted commas which look pretty normal to naked eyes, but not to an intellegent IDE :D #gotcha

Comment: In the image urls as well

Comment: I have replaced them all with ', as you wrote in your answer ( `$('main');`) etc.., but still - doesn't work

Comment: I would assume that's a copy-paste / question issue, or check via a comment (although I did leave them in in the edit)

Comment: Ohh Gawd!!! what are you using to code, I just realized you are using three different types of `single inverted commas`!!!!

Comment: @GustavoZanardini - nice, that works! thank you! but can it change background smoothly? I tried transition, but didn't work as expected.

Comment: @MohdAbdulMujib - well to be honest I've copied most of the script from some thread.. I usually don't work with jQuery